# how to map multi field in java using org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentFactory.jsonBuilder

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

I want to map exactly same [reference_link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_multi_fields.html) by java.

Comment: That link does not seem to exist. Anyways, you need to describe your issue here in any case. Future readers might also have to deal with a broken link and they would be left without understanding the question. That would defeat the primary goal of this Q&A site. So make some effort to properly present your question, and people will make some to answer your question.

Comment: FYI, I fixed the link

Comment: Thanks for fixing this @Val

Comment: yeah got it @user3743222

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i found the solution,what i have done is :
other code above (to start from beginning):-
`.startObject(tags.getTitle()).field("type", "string")
                    .startObject("fields").startObject("raw")
                    .field("type", "string")
                    .field("analyzer", "case_insensitive_sort").endObject()
                    .endObject().endObject()` 
then end code.